# GCP - GKE - image - showing POD and source IP (including x-forwarding for)

Tags: image, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I would like to use the image for Deployment within GCP (GKE) which will be showing the POD name where the service is hosted and the NODE name + source IP and POD/NODE IP address. Is it doable to show also x-forwarded IP?

Comment: Can you describe your deployment in more detail?  It is unclear exactly what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I would like to have a Pod and when I reach it over the http I expect to see pod name and my source Ip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gke-whereami for that https://github.com/theemadnes/gke-whereami

The Source IP should be in the header field

You can use the image from GCP's Artifact registry us-docker.pkg.dev/google-samples/containers/gke/whereami:v1.2.10

Comment: Hi, do you know how I can transfer data variables to the pod? I would like to have variable which will be defined every time when new pod comes run.

Comment: Not sure i understand your question. You want to define environment variables in the pod it self ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to configure a pod with variable. For instance: var1 = pod1, and this var will be taken by pod1, var=pod2, and this time pod 2 will be able to use this var.

Comment: You can define any set of random environment variables on the containers in the pod https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @boredabdel for referencing `whereami` - the canonical repo now is https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes-engine-samples/tree/main/whereami and, while you're always welcome to add your own environment variables for the containers / pods, there's a metadata field via the configmap you can use to specify arbitrary data.

i haven't implemented referencing the source IP, however.